# Rails - How to Redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dns, heroku

I'm looking to learn how to cleanup my app's URLs. My app is powered by Rails 3 on Heroku.

The desired URL is `https://www.example.comite.com`

I'd like to redirect all URLs unlike the above to that URL. Is this a Rails thing or DNS?

Bad URLs:

```
https://example.comite.com
http://www.example.comite.com
http://example.comite.com
```

And if anything is trailing, like `http://www.example.comite.com/photo/1` for the url to be redirected with the path: `https://www.example.comite.com/photo/1`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

DNS records cannot define the protocol for a domain, therefore you can't redirect `http://` to `https://` through DNS. Doing it through the web server configuration is not portable, hard to do, error prone and just plain outdated. This is a job best handled by the Rails router.

```
# beginning of routes.rb 
match "*path" => redirect("https://www.mysite.com/%{path}"), :constraints => { :protocol => "http://" }
match "*path" => redirect("https://www.mysite.com/%{path}"), :constraints => { :subdomain => "" }
```

Comment: This works, but do you need to leave the A records in place?  I was assuming you'd be able to redirect `mysite.com` to `http://www.mysite.com` via DNS, and then once it hit your rails app it would redirect to https using your route contraints.  However, with my DNS redirect `http://mysite.com` redirects as expected, but `https://mysite.com` doesn't (and never hits my rails server for the route contraints to take effect).  I've reverted back to having A records for now, but was just wondering if you knew why the DNS redirect didn't work for `https://mysite.com`.

Comment: there's nothing you can do on the DNS side. As I said, DNS has nothing to do with the protocol. You can redirect a name to another, but not the protocol. It isn't even transmitted to the DNS server. Your browser asks the IP address of `mysite.com` not `http://mysite.com`, and it gets a reply like `REDIRECT www.mysite.com` not `REDIRECT http://www.mysite.com`

Comment: I am not able to redirect from "https://example.com" to "https://www.example.com" by adding above rules in routes

Comment: @Shrinivas they probably won't work unless you put them at the **beginning** of your `routes.rb`

Answer (score 57):

As an extension to [user2100689's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2100689/user2100689/), in Rails 3+ you can use `config.force_ssl = true` in *config/environments/production.rb*

The line can just be uncommented as follows

```
# Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
config.force_ssl = true
```

Answer (score 7):

Because this is Heroku, you cannot use apache or nginx configs.  What you can do is put a before_filter in your ApplicationController, assuming you have 3 or more controllers like 
these below, although of course they will be in separate files

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def redirect_https        
        redirect_to :protocol => "https://" unless request.ssl?
        return true
    end
    before_filter :redirect_https
end
class TypicalController < ApplicationController
    def blah
    end
end
class HomePageController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :redirect_https
end
```

You may also need to fiddle your routes a bit when using devise, but I suspect that was 
just the way we did it so I won't get into those details here, and I've modified the code
above to avoid that complication.

happy hacking.

Comment: This feels like the right way to go, but doesn't answer one key point: how do you transition from `http://mysite.com` to `https://www.mysite.com`?  (Answer the essentially identical question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027916/redirecting-from-http-mysite-com-to-https-secure-mysite-com and get double points!)

Answer (score 7):

Rails 3.1.0 and higher has `force_ssl`, which is a controller method that will redirect to https for non-development environments.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html

Place it in each controller that you want to redirect, or better yet, place it in your ApplicationController:

app/controllers/application.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # ...
  force_ssl
  # ...
end
```

This is a good thing to always include in your apps (and of course you'll have to get a certificate). HTTPS Everywhere!

Comment: Does this protect against SSL stripping?

Comment: I believe this does protect against sslstrip-type attacks. Rails will refuse to serve non-SSL requests by always redirecting to the corresponding HTTPS URL. If sslstrip changes the protocol of the redirect, Rails will simply redirect to HTTPS again.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty CAREFUL, if there is a MITM attack then session cookies will be leaked before the redirect back to https happens. Which means a more advanced sslstrip will pwn your site, and make public wifi's (and spoofed wifis) very dangerous while using your app. To prevent cookies leaking, you need to enable config.use_ssl = true

Comment: [`force_ssl` is the setting that enables secure cookies.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39476254/1589422) I can find no reference to a `use_ssl` setting [in the Rails codebase](https://github.com/rails/rails/search?q=use_ssl), nor in Google.

Answer (score 7):

You can always throw this in your production.rb... `config.use_ssl = true`

Comment: With Rails 5 (and possibly older versions as well), `use_ssl` will do nothing. `force_ssl` is the option that must be set.

Answer (score -5):

DO it in your vhosts file.

Setup a SSL vhost.

In your standard port 80 virtual host. Add this to the config:

```
Redirect permanent / https://www.mysite.com
```

This will forward all port 80 requests to https.

Comment: He's using Heroku and has no access to the web server config like that.