# How to enforce HTTPS inside java cedar stack under Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, https

I've found many question about enforcing HTTPS under heroku but no response are about the java.

Here are the link I found :

Scala : http://www.andersen-gott.com/2012/03/using-unfiltered-and-https-on-heroku.html

Rails : [Rails - How to Redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329176/rails-how-to-redirect-from-http-mysite-com-to-https-www-mysite-com)

Please note that I am using Spring MVC 3.1 so I would prefer a solution based on WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is hte solution based on spring mvc :

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class ForceHerokuSsl extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
         String proto = request.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto");
         return proto == null || "https".equalsIgnoreCase(proto);
    }
}
```

Then in the configuration :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ForceHerokuSslInterceptor());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Servlet Filter that redirects all non-https requests to https:

```
package com.jamesward;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HttpsEnforcer implements Filter {

    private FilterConfig filterConfig;

    public static final String X_FORWARDED_PROTO = "x-forwarded-proto";

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        if (request.getHeader(X_FORWARDED_PROTO) != null) {
            if (request.getHeader(X_FORWARDED_PROTO).indexOf("https") != 0) {
                response.sendRedirect("https://" + request.getServerName() + (request.getPathInfo() == null ? "" : request.getPathInfo()));
                return;
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // nothing
    }
}
```

I did this as a Servlet Filter because I couldn't get a Spring Interceptor to intercept the static asset (resource) requests.

Full source: https://github.com/jamesward/springmvc-https-enforcer

Comment: request.getPathInfo() may return 'null', resulting in a string like this:  'https://yourdomain.comnull', so you might want to check for that before appending it to your redirect URL

Comment: Edited per Erik's comment. I've been fighting this for a while now, and the answer was right under my nose! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but an alternative, configuration-driven approach is to use Spring Security with `requires-channel="https"` on the various `<sec:intercept-url>` tags, in conjunction with Tomcat `RemoteIpValve`, which handles the same proxy headers (`x-forwarded-proto`, etc.) mentioned in the prior answer. The valve changes the behavior of `HttpServletRequest.isSecure()` based on the proxy headers to reflect the protocol reported by the proxy, not the protocol the connector actually received - so any frameworks like Spring that rely on `isSecure()` to Do the Right Thing will behave properly when SSL is offloaded.

[SSL redirects in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13397034/ssl-redirects-in-heroku) has instruction on configuring the valve for use with webapp-runner and Heroku.

Additionally, I suggest using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to let the value be environment over-ridable. E.g., in your Spring Security configuration:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/api/**" requires-channel="${REQUIRES_CHANNEL}" access="..."/>
```

The relevant `application-config.xml` would include something like this:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
  <property name="properties" ref="applicationProperties"/>
</bean>

<bean id="applicationProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath:/application-config.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

The `application-config.properties` file would include `REQUIRES_CHANNEL=http` as a default, then when deployed to Heroku, you set `heroku config:set REQUIRES_CHANNEL=https` to override.

Answer (score 0):

A bit optimized version of James's filter

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HttpsFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if ("http".equalsIgnoreCase(httpReq.getHeader("x-forwarded-proto"))) {
            StringBuffer requestURL = httpReq.getRequestURL();
            httpResp.sendRedirect("https" + requestURL.substring(requestURL.indexOf(":")));
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/elmot/433b56b45f3356a23da067f2cfb26211)