# Can http version of site (as opposed to https) be made unavailable?

Tags: http, https

For apps that take payments and other sensitive data, best practice is undoubtedly to enable https routes.

But I notice the http version of the urls still work (perfectly well), which, if accidentally used *could* expose users to unnecessary risk.

Is it possible to outright disable the http versions?

So far I know that an attempt to access `http://www.google.com/` results in the browser resolving to `https://www.google.com/`. I'm not sure how this works and all the steps involved (is it a simple redirect or something much more), and I'm not sure if users could somehow access (and stay on) the http version, thereby exposing themselves to unnecessary risk.

Note: I do not deal with web everyday, so I apologise if this is a stupid question to those who do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the technology stack you are using:

Let's take for an instance that you are using .net and hosting your website on iis. You can use mod_rewrite to redirect all http requests to their https equivalent: https://serverfault.com/questions/893315/best-way-to-redirect-all-http-to-https-in-iis

Same thing if you are hosting on Apache: [http to https apache redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200501/http-to-https-apache-redirection)

Basically all web servers support this one way or another.

### Edit 1

You can also disable it altogether as seen here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/184791/how-to-disable-non-ssl-connection-on-apache-2-2 but that would limit your users and make them think the service is down. Much better to redirect them to the secure version.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I also found it's incredibly easy to implement the redirect since it's done at application level. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21533827)'s an example that works in a standard ruby on rails application. I'd guess most frameworks would make it just as easy